# How to fetch data from custom component created @hybris side in Spartacus

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, spartacus-storefront

I created custom component "CustomPromotionComponent" by extending "SimpleCMSComponent" @hybris side. It got rendered on spartacus site.

```
0: {slotId: "Section2A-Promotion",…}
components: {component: [{uid: "CustomPromotionComponent",…}]}
component: [{uid: "CustomPromotionComponent",…}]
0: {uid: "CustomPromotionComponent",…}
container: "false"
modifiedtime: "2020-07-25T17:58:35.279+05:30"
name: "Custom Promotion Component"
typeCode: "CustomPromotionComponent"
uid: "CustomPromotionComponent"
uuid: "eyJpdGVtSWQiOiJDdXN0b21Qcm9tb3Rpb25Db21wb25lbnQiLCJjYXRhbG9nSWQiOiJlbGVjdHJvbmljcy1zcGFDb250ZW50Q2F0YWxvZyIsImNhdGFsb2dWZXJzaW9uIjoiT25saW5lIn0="
```

as shown above.

How can I retrieve this data from angular?
I created same component @angular side too but it doesn't work.
i have added my component in .ts file as shown along with this i added my component in custom-page.module.ts also.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
import { CmsComponentData } from '@spartacus/storefront';
import { CmsService} from '@spartacus/core';
import { CMSCustomPromotionComponent } from '../cms.custom-promotion-component';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-custom-promotion',
  templateUrl: './custom-promotion.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./custom-promotion.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class CustomPromotionComponent implements OnInit {

  componentData$: Observable<CMSCustomPromotionComponent> = this.componentData.data$;

  constructor( protected componentData: CmsComponentData<CMSCustomPromotionComponent>, 
    protected cmsService: CmsService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.componentData$);
  }

}
```

html part:

```
<p *ngIf="(componentData$ | async) as data" [innerHTML]="data.name"></p>
```

```
ConfigModule.withConfig({
      cmsComponents: {
        CustomPromotionComponent: {
          component: CustomPromotionComponent,
        }
      },
    } as CmsConfig)
```

created cmscustomcomponent by extending cmscomponent.

```
import { CmsComponent } from '@spartacus/core';

export interface CMSCustomPromotionComponent extends CmsComponent {
    container?: string;
}
```

While rendering on storefront i am getting below error:

```
core.js:6228 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CustomPromotionComponent -> CmsComponentData]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CustomPromotionComponent -> CmsComponentData]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CmsComponentData!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[CustomPromotionComponent -> CmsComponentData]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[CustomPromotionComponent -> CmsComponentData]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CmsComponentData!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/SAP/spartacus/blob/develop/projects/storefrontlib/src/cms-components/content/paragraph/ as a reference.

This is the interesting part:

```
constructor(public component: CmsComponentData<CmsParagraphComponent>) {}
```

Comment: i have updated my code snippet, but now i am getting error in storefront, please refer to error updated in the explanation.

Comment: Your code snippets shows correct to me. Maybe try to restart your yarn process.

Comment: i have already tried restarting yarn, getting same error.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2890959/tobi-or-not-tobi
could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try giving CmsComponentData in the constructor, check whether it resolves the issue or not

Comment: Try adding more details to your answer eg. provide root cause of the problem and definite solution to the problem. Consider adding a comment to the question otherwise instead of adding an answer.

Comment: CmsComponentData is already there in the constructor, also if you are telling something else could you please explain little bit more.